# Weave number rows together with python

Tags: python, addition, rows

I am trying to write a program in Python to weave two lines of numbers togehter. Like this:

these two rows:

```
1,3,5,7,9

2,4,6,8,10
```

weave to give output as:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

But I have no clue how to do this, (I'm just starting out with python)

Comment: yes, they are in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
l2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
sum(zip(l1, l2), ())
# (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
a=[1,3,5]
b=[2,4,6]
```

The zip function is exactly what you are searching for

```
zip(a,b) # [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

The Solution is now to flatten the result:

```
[item for sublist in zip(a,b) for item in sublist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the length of both is list are same
You can achive it by only using loops.

```
l1=[1,3,5,7,9]
l2=[2,4,6,8,10]
l3=l1+l2
l4=[]
j=len(l1)
for i in range(0,len(l1)):
    l4.append(l3[i])
    l4.append(l3[j])
    j+=1
print l4
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the first list and then sort the result:

```
In [44]:  list1 = [1,3,5,7,9]

In [45]:  list2 = [2,4,6,8,10]

In [46]:  list1.extend(list2)

In [50]: list1.sort()

In [51]: list1
Out[51]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```